# Import Error: No module named 'PySide2'

Tags: python, qtcreator

Пишу:
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication

qt creator пишет Import Error: No module named 'PySide2'

я установил PySide2 через pip:
pip install PySide2

в чем проблема? Как исправить?
Linux.

Comment: Установили куда? Импортируете откуда? В виртуальных окружениях не запутались?

Comment: возможно в этом проблема. Как решить, подскажите пожалуйста. я не создавал виртуальных окружений.

Comment: qt creator показывает, что доступно три интерпретатора питона. пробовал устанавливать по умолчанию разные. не помогает.